# Exact multinomial goodness-of-fit test as a normality test

Tags: normal-distribution, binning, exact-test

We have a practical real-life problem in an open source Linux related project. And I would like to hear an expert review/opinion about the way we are trying to solve this problem. It's been more than 15 years since I graduated and my mathematics skills are a little bit rusty.

There are some electronic devices, which may work at different configurable clock frequencies. A valid clock frequency must be a multiple of 24 MHz. Different units of the same type may have slightly different reliability (one unit may be reliable at 720 MHz, but another may fail already at 672 MHz). There is also a tool, which can test whether the device is working reliable or not. The currently collected statistics from 23 different units is presented in a table [[1](https://linux-sunxi.org/index.php?title=Xunlong_Orange_Pi_PC&oldid=17603#DRAM_clock_speed_limit)]. Obtaining more test samples is difficult. Even these 23 samples took a lot of time to get collected. Here is the list of the clock frequencies, at which the devices have been confirmed to fail the reliability test:
`4 units  : PASS <= 648 MHz, FAIL >= 672 MHz (clock frequency bin #1)
10 units : PASS <= 672 MHz, FAIL >= 696 MHz (clock frequency bin #2)
4 units  : PASS <= 696 MHz, FAIL >= 720 MHz (clock frequency bin #3)
4 units  : PASS <= 720 MHz, FAIL >= 744 MHz (clock frequency bin #4)
1 unit   : PASS <= 744 MHz, FAIL >= 768 MHz (clock frequency bin #5)`

The transition points from the PASS to the FAIL state can be assumed to be somewhere in the middle of each 24 MHz interval and the whole set of clock frequency samples may look like this:
`x = [660, 660, 660, 660, 684, 684, 684, 684, 684, 684, 684, 684, 684, 684, 708, 708, 708, 708, 732, 732, 732, 732, 756]`

Overall the distribution somewhat resembles the normal distribution by just looking at the histogram. But it's best to verify this. I tried a few normality tests, such as Shapiro-Wilk, Kolmogorov-Smirnov and Anderson-Darling. However they need more samples than are available. In addition, the normality tests don't like ties, and we are essentially dealing with a binned data (using the 24MHz intervals).

So instead of doing the standard normality tests mentioned above, I tried to approximate the experimental data as a normal distribution and then do an exact multinomial test using the Xnomial library for R. It checks if the theoretical probabilities for each of the available frequency bins agrees with the experimental data. More specifically, we calculate the sample *mean* ($695.478261$) and sample *variance* ($26.949228^2$) of this data set. Then using the CDF of the normal distribution with these *mean* and *variance* parameters, we get theoretical probabilities for each bin. For example $\Phi(696) - \Phi(672)$ should give us the probability of having a device that passes the reliability test at 672 MHz but fails it at 696 MHz. Because each device belongs to some frequency bin and each frequency bin has its own theoretical probability, this whole setup is nothing else but a perfect example of a multinomial distribution. And we can do a goodness-of-fit test by comparing the theoretical probabilities with the actual numbers of observed samples. If the p-value looks ok, then our null hypothesis about having a normal distribution is not rejected yet. Does this approach look reasonable?

And at the end of the day we want to pick a single clock frequency, which is reasonably reliable on all devices of this type. **If we do have a normal distribution** here, then the probability of having reliability problems at 648MHz is estimated to be ~3.9% and the probability of having problems at 624MHz is estimated to be ~0.4% (though there were no devices failing at 624 MHz or 648 MHz in the current sample set of 23 devices). But **if we don't have a normal distribution**, then we have to resort to something like Chebyshev's inequality, which is very conservative and overestimates probabilities. Since we have a one-tailed case (we are only looking at the low clock frequencies), the [lower semivariance Chebyshev's inequality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219046) seemed to be the most appropriate. But it gives ~12.8% as the failure probability upper bound for 648 MHz and ~5.7% for 624 MHz.

Are there any obvious problems? Can anything be done better? We also have the results of processing these 23 samples presented as another table [[2](https://linux-sunxi.org/index.php?title=Xunlong_Orange_Pi_PC&oldid=17603#DRAM_clock_speed_limit_.28automated_statistical_analysis.29)] for your convenience.

Thanks!

Comment: "I tried to approximate the experimental data as a normal distribution and then do an exact multinomial test using the Xnomial library for R" I think we'd need a little more detail on the approach before saying whether it's reasonable or not. And is there any reason to think the distribution of failure frequencies will have a normal distribution in the first place?

Comment: "I think we'd need a little more detail on the approach" - I have updated the question with additional details about the exact multinomial test.

Comment: Chebyshev's ineqaulity has such low power that it's never used in practice to test for normality, it's only for textbooks. So, if you managed to violate it it means that the deviation is really large. It must be visually obvious.

Comment: As for the reason to think that we have a normal distribution. We don't have any good reasons other than the fact that the normal distribution is pretty common thanks to the central limit theorem (the printed circuit board of the device may have many small imperfections in various places). We are lucky if the distribution is in fact normal, but we also have the Chebyshev's inequality based estimate as a fallback in order not to put all eggs into one basket.

Comment: *"Chebyshev's ineqaulity has such low power that it's never used in practice to test for normality"* - Chebyshev's inequality is not used as a test for normality here. I only tried to look at it as a possible backup solution to pick a safe clock frequency if we reject the normality distribution null hypothesis. And yes, Chebyshev's inequality does not look very useful because using it as a selection criteria, we would need to reduce the clock frequency way too much to be "safe".

Comment: 1. It's not made clear but do all (or essentially all) devices succeed at very low frequencies and fail at high frequencies? 2. as you pass to higher frequencies, do they switch (from not failing to failing) *only once*? (i.e. you can't fail at 648 but succeed at 672 .... if this is so, then it would make sense that it's of interest to figure out where they tend to switch) 3. Are the data actually tabulated frequencies for "the lowest frequency at which the device failed"?

Comment: Why not perform a logistic regression?

Comment: Whether or not all the answers to my earlier questions were to be "yes", I don't think it makes any sense to test data like these for normality.

Comment: *"1. It's not made clear but do all (or essentially all) devices succeed at very low frequencies and fail at high frequencies?"* - yes, *"2. as you pass to higher frequencies, do they switch (from not failing to failing) only once? (i.e. you can't fail at 648 but succeed at 672 .... if this is so, then it would make sense that it's of interest to figure out where they tend to switch)"* - yes, but we don't have better accuracy  *"3. Are the data actually tabulated frequencies for "the lowest frequency at which the device failed"?"* - I have updated this information to make it more readable.

Comment: *"Why not perform a logistic regression?"* - that's a good question, I need to read up on logistic regressions.

Comment: *"I don't think it makes any sense to test data like these for normality"* - Can you elaborate on this? Are there too few samples available to make a reasonable analysis? Or is there a better method to estimate the probability of encountering a device, which would be unreliable when clocked at 648 MHz?

Comment: There is much in this post that is puzzling. I don't see how you could possibly apply Chebyshev's Inequality, because you would need the *true* mean and variance of a distribution, but all you can do is estimate them. Whether to apply Normality tests is questionable; whether it's meaningful to apply them to these data is also questionable (as you rightly point out); and I would also question whether you have actually applied them as intended, because they work just fine with sample sizes much smaller than you report. And what does "reasonably reliable" mean? Why not just pick a low frequency?

Comment: (1) Using the mid-points of the intervals to estimate the mean & variance isn't the best approach - if the data were normally distributed an observation in a given interval would more likely be towards the end closer to the mean. (2) Did you take into account that the theoretical probabilities are estimated from the data rather than pre-specified?

Comment: *"(1) Using the mid-points of the intervals to estimate the mean & variance isn't the best approach - if the data were normally distributed an observation in a given interval would more likely be towards the end closer to the mean."* - thanks, is it something like this - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60256/standard-deviation-of-binned-observations ?

Comment: *"There is much in this post that is puzzling. I don't see how you could possibly apply Chebyshev's Inequality, because you would need the true mean and variance of a distribution, but all you can do is estimate them. "* - wikipedia suggests that it is possible to use sample mean and sample standard deviation with Chebyshev's inequality after applying some correction - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Finite_samples (I have done a sloppy job and did not take this into account yet)

Comment: *"Whether to apply Normality tests is questionable; whether it's meaningful to apply them to these data is also questionable (as you rightly point out); and I would also question whether you have actually applied them as intended, because they work just fine with sample sizes much smaller than you report."* - normality tests, such as Shapiro-Wilk, don't like ties (samples which have exactly the same value), ties exist in binned data, and this results in a staircase-alike Q-Q plot and a failure to detect normality.

Comment: @SiarheiSiamashka http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/introduction-to-logistic-regression/

Comment: *"And what does "reasonably reliable" mean? Why not just pick a low frequency?"* - that's the point of this whole ordeal. For this particular data set, the main question may be formulated as **"What would be a sharp upper bound for the probability of encountering a device which fails at 648 MHz? Considering that none of the devices from the current sample set fail at 648 MHz."**

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, they have been very helpful. I'm new to the statistics field and to the stackexchange platform in general. Now I see that the question has not been formulated in the best possible way. Now it's more like *"We have this particular practical problem. And I have this solution, based on the exact multinomial test. I also have a backup solution, based on the Chebyshev's inequality. Is it OK? Yes/No"*. And I see that it's difficult to get a meaningful answer this way. Now I wonder if I should have posted a question with the task description and added two answers myself?

Comment: So that other people could propose their alternative answers. And also comment about my two current answers, explaining why they are not good enough.

Comment: I thought the q. was asked pretty well - it's quite common on this site for comments to prompt for some necessary clarification. If it's not been answered yet it's probably because there's a lot to it: (1) is your approach appropriate?, & (2) have you implemented either solution correctly?

Comment: @Scortchi Yes, also this question has too many parts in it and could have been split it into something like "Statistical perils of overclocking electronic devices" (a real-life problem to solve), "Normality test for a small binned sample set" (the multinomial stuff, regardless of whether it is useful or not) and ["The practical use of the lower/upper semivariance adaptation of Chebyshev's inequality for sampled data"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219046) (I have just posted it). I'm not in a hurry to get answers, but I was worried about not having this question well structured.

Comment: You are right about the need to have a correct implementation of every method. It's very nice to have helpful comments and the population vs. sample mean/variance was a very good point.

Comment: @MarceloVentura thanks a lot for the logistic regression suggestion. I have implemented this (mostly by adapting an existing example from the Internet) and it seems to work fine. The predicted PASS/FAIL probabilities for 648 MHz and 624 MHz made by it are very close to the predictions from my normal distribution approximation model. Should I add the details about the logistic regression implementation to the question text? Or do you prefer to maybe post it as your answer?

Comment: @SiarheiSiamashka since I suggested changing the original question to another, it seems to me that it would be unfair with the people that took the effort to answer the original formulation. I guess it would be more appropriate to post a new question.

Comment: @SiarheiSiamashka and then add an edit to this question pointing to the new one.

Answer (score 7):

*If* it makes sense to start off assuming that the "true" clock frequencies at which failure would occur are normally distributed ...

(1) You wouldn't expect the "true" values to be uniformly distributed within each interval. So using the midpoints to estimate the mean & standard deviation is more or less dodgy depending on how fine the intervals are—in particular the standard deviation  will be over-estimated because the distribution of "true" values within each interval is skewed towards the mean.

The log-likelihood function for the normal mean $\mu$ & standard deviation $\sigma$ is

$$\ell(\mu,\sigma) =  4\cdot\log\left[\Phi\left(\frac{672-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{648-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right] + 10\cdot\log\left[\Phi\left(\frac{696-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{672-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right] + \ldots$$

where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution function. So maximize it numerically to get maximum-likelihood estimates for the parameters:

```
# normal log-likelihood function
norm.log.lik.func <- function(par, freq) {
  sum(freq*log(pnorm(upp,par[1],par[2])-pnorm(low,par[1],par[2])))
}

# function for Nelder-Mead maximization of likelihood function
fit.norm <- function(freq){
  optim(par=c(mu.init,sigma.init),freq=freq,fn=norm.log.lik.func, control=list(fnscale=-1))
}

# observations - frequencies & interval bounds
freq.obs <- c(0,4,10,4,4,1,0)
upp <- c(648,672,696,720,744,768,Inf)
low <- c(-Inf,648,672,696,720,744,768)

# calculate "mid-point" estimates of mean & s.d. to uses as initial values
2:(length(freq.obs)-1) -> s
sum((low[s]+upp[s])/2*freq.obs[s])/sum(freq.obs) -> mu.init
sqrt(sum(((low[s]+upp[s])/2)^2*freq.obs[s])/sum(freq.obs) - mu.init^2) -> sigma.init

# get maximum-likelihood estimates of mean & s.d 
fit.norm(freq.obs) -> norm.fit.obs
norm.fit.obs$par
```

[image: profile likelihood]

For these data $\hat\mu=695.5$, about the same as the rough estimate, & $\hat\sigma=25.41$, a little smaller.

(2) The exact multinomial test you've used as a goodness-of-fit test requires a prespecified multinomial distribution as a null hypothesis, whereas yours is estimated from the data. The effect is to make it unnecessarily conservative—any given amount of discrepancy of the observations with the null, as measured by the test statistic, should become more a bit more surprising when you take into account that the null in question has already been picked to minimize such discrepancy (within the constraints of normality).

The log likelihood-ratio test statistic (the deviance) is conveniently calculated if you've followed the approach in (1):
$$G=2.\cdot\left(4\cdot \log 4 +10\cdot\log 10 + \ldots - 23\cdot \log 23 -\ell(\hat\mu,\hat\sigma)\right)$$
Its asymptotic distribution depends only on the difference in the degrees of freedom you have to fit a multinomial compared with a normal. I think your table's densely enough populated for the asymptotic approximation to do for most purposes—or you could try a double bootstrap to estimate the p-value:

```
# 0 log 0 -> 0
xlogx <- function(x) ifelse(x==0, 0, x*log(x))

# deviance function
calc.deviance <- function(freq, norm.ml.fit.log.lik){
  2*(sum(xlogx(freq) - freq*log(sum(freq))) - norm.ml.fit.log.lik)
}

# simulation function
sim.samp <- function(fit){
  table(cut(rnorm(sum(freq.obs),fit$par[1],fit$par[2]),unique(c(low,upp))))
}

# calculate observed deviance
calc.deviance(freq.obs, norm.fit.obs$value) -> deviance.obs
deviance.obs

# set up for double bootstrap
B <- 1500
C <- 350
# deviance distribution from outer bootstrap
deviance.boot <- numeric(B)
# p-value distribution from inner bootstrap
p.boot <- numeric(B)

# outer bootstrap
for (i in 1:B){
  print(i)
  sim.samp(norm.fit.obs) -> freq.boot
  fit.norm(freq.boot) -> norm.fit.boot
  calc.deviance(freq.boot,norm.fit.boot$value) -> deviance.boot[i]
  deviance.boot2 <- numeric(C)
  # inner bootstrap
  for (j in 1:C){
    sim.samp(norm.fit.boot) -> freq.boot2
    fit.norm(freq.boot2) -> norm.fit.boot2
    calc.deviance(freq.boot2,norm.fit.boot2$value) -> deviance.boot2[j]
  }
  mean(deviance.boot2 >= deviance.boot[i]) -> p.boot[i]
}
# unadjusted p-value (basic bootstrap)
p.unadj <- mean(deviance.boot >= deviance.obs)
# adjusted p-value (double bootstrap)
p.adj <- mean(p.boot<=p.unadj)
# asymptotic p-value
p.asymp <-1-pchisq(deviance.obs, df=length(freq.obs)-2-1)
```

The distribution of the p-value got from the outer bootstrap is estimated with the inner bootstrap, & deviates somewhat from uniformity, requiring adjustment:

[image: pboot]

The adjusted, double-bootstrap estimate of the p-value for these data is 0.314; compared with 0.324 from the test using the asymptotic approximation.

(3) Confidence intervals would be a useful supplement to point estimates of the distribution function of failures at a given clock frequency. You could estimate these from the profile likelihood:

```
# reparametrize log likelihood function
norm.log.lik.func.2 <- function(mu, prob, quant, freq){
sigma <- (quant-mu)/qnorm(prob)
norm.log.lik.func(c(mu,sigma),freq)
}

# profile log likelihood function
profile.log.lik.func <- Vectorize(function(prob, quant, freq){
  optim(par=mu.init, prob=prob, quant=quant, freq=freq, fn=norm.log.lik.func.2, control=list(fnscale=-1))$value
}, vectorize.args=c("prob"))

# calculate profile for quantile of interest e.g. 648
probs <- seq(0.001,0.20, 0.001)
profile.log.lik.func(probs, 648, freq.obs)-norm.fit.obs$value -> pll
```

[image: profile likelihood]

Or by bootstrapping—with the double bootstrap again or perhaps with Efron's BCa method. In any case note that, given the (strong) assumption of normality, failure rates of up to around 10% at a clock frequency of 648 don't seem especially implausible.

(4) An investigation of the sensitivity of this approach to some kinds of violation of the normality assumption seems advisable: how powerful is the goodness-of-fit test to detect them & what effect do they have on estimates?