# The practical use of the lower/upper semivariance adaptation of Chebyshev's inequality for sampled data

Tags: sample, probability-inequalities, mean

The wikipedia article about Chebyshev's inequality also lists a one-sided [sharpened variant, based on upper/lower semivariances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Semivariances). It is additionally mentioned there there that *"The inequality with the lower semivariance has been found to be of use in estimating downside risk in finance and agriculture"*, but I have troubles accessing the referenced papers (they all seem to require a registration, though the [first page](http://ajae.oxfordjournals.org/content/64/2/298.extract) of the *"Using the Semivariance to Estimate Safety-First Rules"* paper by Peter Berck and Jairus M. Hihn appears to be available for free and already contains enough information).

There is also a rather informative question ["Does a sample version of the one-sided Chebyshev inequality exist?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82419/does-a-sample-version-of-the-one-sided-chebyshev-inequality-exist) about a similar topic already answered here. My current understanding is that specifically looking at the upper and lower [semivariances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Semivariance) separately may make sense for substantially asymmetric distributions. It can be probably interpreted as just throwing away the samples above/below the population mean and replacing them with the mirror-reflected samples from the other tail. Then the ordinary Chebyshev's inequality is getting applied to this modified data set.

The question is about how applicable is this lower/upper semivariance variant of Chebyshev's inequality for dealing with sampled data. Is it theoretically sound? Or is it more like some kind of heuristics invented by the finance/agriculture folks?